# $(TargetDir) empty for Microsoft Word Add-In project in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, vsto, word-addins

The $(TargetDir) property seems to be disabled for Word Add-In projects on Visual Studio 2017.

I'm creating a Microsoft Word Add-In project in Visual Studio 2017 using C# and .NET. I need my Add-In to access an XSD schema file in order to validate a user-loaded XML. My first thought was to copy the XSD file from my project directory to the target directory using the following post-build event:

```
xcopy "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)TestSchema.xsd" "$(TargetDir)"
```

but this seems to be impossible since the $(TargetDir) property is an empty string.

Is there another way to achieve this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Updating the file properties for TestSchema.xsd to:

**Build Action:** Content

**Copy to Output Directory:** Copy if newer

Seems to have done the trick.